# Display product attributes not set for variation on Woocommerce product variations

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, product-variations

I have custom tab on each product variation with some 'variation description' static content and that I have displayed on product page as well in > product summary when I select a variation *(like in [this link](https://woocommerce-224624-828355.cloudwaysapps.com/dickenbergh-westfalen/?attribute_pa_seizoen=4-seizoenen-dekbed&attribute_pa_maat=140-x-200))*.

And now I need to display the same on shop page in product loop *(see my [shop page](https://woocommerce-224624-828355.cloudwaysapps.com/shop/))*.

OR even better to display specific attributes. I tried this code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'custom_before_title' );
function custom_before_title() {
    global $product;

    echo '<h4><b>Seizoen:</b>' . $product->get_attribute('pa_seizoen') .'</h4>';
    echo '<h4><b>Maat:</b> ' . $product->get_attribute('pa_maat') .'</h4>';
    echo '<h4><b>Tijk:</b> ' . $product->get_attribute('pa_tijk-weving') .'</h4>';
    echo '<h4><b>Vulkracht:</b> ' . $product->get_attribute('pa_fullkraft[') .'</h4>';
    echo '<h4><b>Vulkracht:</b> ' . $product->get_attribute('pa_vulling') .'</h4>';
}
```

But whatever I do I get same result, it displays only product attributes that are in the product variations: first two "season and size".

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a plugin (or some customizations) that is displaying on your shop page (or archive pages) each product variations individually.

So you need to get the parent variable product for other product attributes that are not set for variations *(and the product description or other required related data)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'custom_before_title' );
function custom_before_title() {
    global $product;

    if( $seizoen = $product->get_attribute('pa_seizoen') ) {
        echo '<h4><strong>Seizoen:</strong>' . $seizoen . '</h4>';
    }
    if( $maat = $product->get_attribute('pa_maat') ) {
        echo '<h4><strong>Maat:</strong> ' . $maat . '</h4>';
    }

    $parent_id = $product->get_parent_id(); // Get the parent Variable Product ID
    // Below, all Parent variable product data
    if( $parent_id > 0 && $parent_product = wc_get_product($parent_id) ) {
        if( $tijk_weving = $parent_product->get_attribute('pa_tijk-weving') ) {
            echo '<h4><strong>Tijk:</strong> ' . $tijk_weving . '</h4>';
        }
        if( $fullkraft = $parent_product->get_attribute('pa_fullkraft') ) {
            echo '<h4><strong>Vulkracht:</strong> ' . $fullkraft . '</h4>';
        }
        if( $vulling = $parent_product->get_attribute('pa_vulling') ) {
            echo '<h4><strong>Vulling:</strong> ' . $vulling . '</h4>';
        }

        // Display the parent variable product description
        echo '<p><strong>Beschrijving:</strong> ' . $parent_product->get_description() . '</p>';

        // Display the parent variable product short description
        echo '<p><strong>Korte beschrijving:</strong> ' . $parent_product->get_short_description() . '</p>';
    }  

    // Display the product variation description
    // echo '<p><strong>Beschrijving:</strong> ' . $product->get_description() . '</p>';

    // Display the product variation weight
    // echo '<p><strong>Gewicht:</strong> ' . wc_format_weight( $product->get_weight() ) . '</p>';

    // Display the product variation dimensions
    // echo '<p><strong>Dimensies:</strong> ' . $product->get_dimensions() . '</p>';
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work now.

Comment: hey mate, this is working 99% perfect! :)
THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!
Only thing: pa_fullkraft doesnt appear on the page and of course I have no idea why :) - you can refresh the /shop page

Comment: @GoranLukic Maybe this product taxonomy is `pa_full-kraft` (something a bit different). You need to check as nobody can do it for you.